# fetching data from mysql via python3

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from mysql , but its giving me error :( would anyone help ? 
i have place the codes below also the screen shot of error , i also want to fetch all the data and not just one but for now i have used fetchone

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pymysql

# Open database connection
db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","123456","blue" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE \WHERE username  'Umair'" 
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
   data = cursor.fetchone()
   print ("Database version : %s ",data)


except:
   print ("Error: unable to fetch data")

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

it's giving the following error

[image]

Comment: The error message does not match the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just my two cents on this...

Here are a couple of things to consider:

1. You do not require the `\` in the sql query,
2. You might want to do `print("Database version: %s" % data)`,
3. You should try and use `cursor.fetchall()` to retrieve back data if there are multiple rows of data as a tuple `(5,6)` as an example,
4. But if there is only one row then by all means use `cursor.fetchone()`,
5. And what is the `except` clause actually trying to 'raise', maybe a database connection failure or some sort of data type response that you were expecting and didn't get back from the DB.

Hope this helps out.

Comment: thanks and please do tell how you print values if you use cursor.fetchall() function ?

Comment: same as how you would print the dataset from `cursor.fetchone()` or you could just do `print(cursor.fetchall())` as well...

Comment: but if i want to store each values to distinct variable and then print ?

Comment: look into `for` loops for that.